# On conditions for Plancherel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

If we have real functions such that $f \in L^1$ and $g \in L^2$, do we still have always the following equality, providing left hand-side is well defined (Plancherel theorem ?) :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(x)  \overline{\hat{g}(x)} dx$$

(theorem is often given for $f$ and $g$ in $L^1 \cap L^2$, but what is the widest form of this relation without involving distributions ?) If above equality is not always true, any counter-example ?

Comment: The left side may not exist for $f \in L^{1}$ and $g \in L^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I modified my question to be more precise.

Comment: The actual Plancherel theorem has a few complex conjugates. (No, specifying that $f$ is real-valued does not imply that $\hat f$ is real-valued.) Your version is simply wrong: If $f=g=\chi_{[0,1]}$ then $\int f^2=||f||_2^2=||\hat f||_2^2>\left|\int\left(\hat f\right)^2\right|$.

Comment: Thanks, question corrected.

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "the LHS is well-defined". (As usual in Fourier transforms) use Gaussian regularization to obtained a sequence of well-defined integrals to which you can apply Plancherel.